# Entity Framewor Core Database.SetInitializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

O `Entity Framework Core` tem o `Database.SetInitializer()`?

Comment: Tente explicar melhor sua pergunta para que alguém possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem esse método que antes era utilizado na versão `Entity Framework 6.x`, com o `Entity Framework Core` é utilizado para oções do seu contexto `DbContextOptions` (`DbContextOptions<T>`).

O `Database.SetInitializer()` é uma forma de informar qual estratégia utilizar na inicialização na sua base de dados com `Code First` e pode variar a sua configuração:

- `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`

  Cria a base de dados e suas respectivas tabelas se não existir.
- `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`

  Exclui a base de dados se houve alterações em suas entidades e cria novamente o banco de dados e suas respectivas tabelas.
- `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`

  Exclui a base de dados se a mesma existir e reecria todas as vezes que o seu programa foi iniciado, diferente do anterior que só exclui a base se houver alteração, nesse caso ele exclui e cria novamente a sua base de dados.
- `Custom DB Initializer`

  Cria um inicializador ou estratégia com sua próprias configurações.

Se ainda quiser anular a estratégia é só escrever no parâmetro `null`

```
Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
```

---

No `Entity Framework Core` é mais simples a chamada desse processo de inicialização com os métodos:

- `Database.EnsureCreated();`

  Cria a base de dados e suas respectivas tabelas se não existir.
- `Database.EnsureDeleted();`

  Exclui a base de dados se existir.

<sub>**Referencia:**</sub>

- [Database Initialization Strategies in EF 6 Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)
- [Configurando um DbContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)